# How to push Loading View to Tab Bar Controller View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

Hi I have been looking around for this solution but cannot find it.
Have created a loading view controller to show all the loading process which has UILabel, UIActivityIndicator. After finishing loading I want to push to a tab bar controller view. 
But the tricky part is I have three different NSOperations working while loading the data. Cannot figure out when to push the view from the loading view controller to the tab bar controller.

Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be simple enough. Have each operation call into a single shared method when it completes; that method should check each operation’s isFinished. If all three are done, the whole thing’s ready, and you can bring up your main tab-bar controller.

Comment: But where should I be calling my single shared method like on my Application Delegate?

Comment: Also I have function call didFinishParsing which basically indicates if my parsing has been done and returns the result with the arraylist which calls [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(handleLoadedApps:) withObject:appList waitUntilDone:YES];                                                  I am not sure how to handle each operation call since I have assigned a delegate to each one of the nsoperation separately and have three different nsoperationqueue.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle this is to show add loading view (i.e. custom UIView) on top of your views, and remove it when the operations are complete.  Within the controller where you are launching your NSOperations, you can add the view.  Then in a callback method that fires when all the operations are complete, you can remove that loading view.  This way you won't need a separate controller just for the loading view.

I've used the example on this site in the past:  http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html